# Django 1.8: Join latest entry to foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, join

Assume I have a simple model (borrowed from django docs):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    pubdate = models.DateField()
```

I want to get a list of authors and their latest book, where it's possible that the author has no books. I can do this with a raw query, but can it be done efficiently within the confines of the ORM (ie without hitting the database repeatedly)?

The best I've come up with is:

```
for a in Author.objects.prefetch_related('book_set'):
    a.book_set.latest('pubdate')
```

This results in an additional query per author. It seems latest cannot be determined with the prefetched queryset.

Appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by explicitly defining the prefetch queryset to get just the latest book for each author. This lets me use `.all()` which will only contain the latest book (or none), and doesn't cause another query.

```
latest_books = Book.objects.annotate(latest=Max('author__book__pubdate')).filter(pubdate=F('latest'))

for a in Author.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('book_set', queryset=b_query)):
    a.book_set.all()[0]
```